# Separate last digit to new column in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm starting with pyspark...
I have the following problem and I'm trying separate the last digit of each id into a  new column:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|         Name        |      Number      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          Bob        |       34789      |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

to this:

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|         Name        |      Number_1    |      Number_2       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|          Bob        |       3478       |          9          |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code.

`UDF` to split given number

```
scala> val splitNumber = udf((d:String) => (d.init,d.last), new StructType().add("number_1","string",true).add("numer_2","string",true))
```

Applying `UDF`

```
scala> 
df
.withColumn("number",splitNumber($"number"))
.select($"name",$"number.*")
.show(false)

+----+--------+-------+
|name|number_1|numer_2|
+----+--------+-------+
|Bob |3478    |9      |
+----+--------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out. you can first use `regexp_extract` to get the last digit to create a new column and use `regexp_replace` to replace the last digit with empty string ''.

```
   from pyspark.sql import functions as F

    df.show()

    # +----+------+
    # |name|number|
    # +----+------+
    # | bob| 34789|
    # +----+------+

    df.withColumn("number_1",F.regexp_replace(F.col('number'),r'(\d$)','')).withColumn("number_2", F.regexp_extract(F.col('number'), r'(\d$)',1)).withColumn("number_1", F.regexp_replace(F.col('number'), r'(\d$)', '')).drop(F.col('number')).show()


    # +----+--------+--------+
    # |name|number_1|number_2|
    # +----+--------+--------+
    # | bob|    3478|       9|
    # +----+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **`substring`** function to extract the value and create new columns.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#+----+------+
#|Name|Number|
#+----+------+
#| Bob| 34789|
#+----+------+

from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df.withColumn("number_1",expr("substring(Number,1,length(Number)-1)")).\
withColumn("number_2",substring(col("Number"),-1,1)).\
drop("Number").\
show()

df.withColumn("number_1",expr("substring(Number,1,length(Number)-1)")).\
withColumn("number_2",expr("substring(number,-1,1)")).\
drop("Number").\
show()
#+----+--------+--------+
#|Name|number_1|number_2|
#+----+--------+--------+
#| Bob|    3478|       9|
#+----+--------+--------+
```

Comment: @CVM, just an FYI, Its not recommended to use `udf` as it decreases the performance instead use inbuilt functions when possible...!